# Amazon RDS Free Tier - Cannot view Free Tier for Oracle RDS

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds

I'm trying to create an Oracle DB in the Amazon RDS cloud but I can't find the free tier option.

I just created my account a few days ago. Because I will not occupy it with anything productive, just for development I do not demand many requirements.

Is there any configuration that I am missing?

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IncMe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS does not provide Oracle as part of the Free tier scheme.

From AWS documentation:

- 750 hours of Amazon RDS Single-AZ db.t2.micro, db.t3.micro, and db.t4g.micro Instances usage running MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL databases each month. If running more than one instance, usage is aggregated across instance classes.
- 750 hours of Amazon RDS Single-AZ db.t2.micro Instance usage running SQL Server (running SQL Server Express Edition) each month.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/free/